# Configuring JanusGraph to use ElasticSearch and Cassandra via Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, graph, cassandra, janusgraph

I am trying to create a schema using janusgraph, and use cassandra as a backend storage, and use elastic search as indexer. connect to JanusGraph using the following code:

```
Graph graph = GraphFactory.open(CONFIG_FILE);
```

the content of the config file is:

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory

storage.backend=cassandrathrift

storage.hostname=127.0.0.1

storage.cassandra.keyspace=JanusGraph

cache.db-cache = true

cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20

cache.db-cache-time = 180000

cache.db-cache-size = 0.25

index.search.backend=elasticsearch

index.search.hostname=127.0.0.1

index.search.port=9300
```

the way i create the index is as follow:

```
 VertexLabel user = mgt.makeVertexLabel(USER).make();
    PropertyKey userName = 
    mgt.makePropertyKey(USER_NAME).dataType(String.class).make();

    //building mixed index (i.e. we use external indexer)
    mgt.buildIndex(indexName(USER, USER_NAME), Vertex.class).
    addKey(userName, Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).
    indexOnly(user).
    buildMixedIndex(BACKING_INDEX);
```

as you see, i first create the vertex then i index some property.

when i run the code without the use of indexer, i didn't get problems, but when i use indexer i get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementation class: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex

at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:60)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:476)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getIndexes(Backend.java:463)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:148)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1840)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.<init>(StandardJanusGraph.java:138)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:160)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:131)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:78)
    at mounaf.janusgraph.Schema.<init>(Schema.java:61)
    at mounaf.janusgraph.BuiltinQueries.main(BuiltinQueries.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:56)
    ... 10 more
```

can you help me to get through this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting **ClassNotFoundException** `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex`

I think you haven't added the janusgraph elasticsearch dependency in your `pom.xml` file.
Add the below dependency in your `pom.xml` file to fix this problem

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>janusgraph-es</artifactId>
        <version>${janusgraph.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember having problems to use the openManagement method in java but i used the client.submit(String gremlin) to configure my schema and indexes and it worked.

```java
client.submit("mgt = graph.openManagement()\n" +
"user = mgt.makeVertexLabel(USER).make()\n" +
"userName = mgt.makePropertyKey(USER_NAME).dataType(String.class).make()\n" +
"mgt.buildIndex(indexName(USER, USER_NAME), Vertex.class).addKey(userName, Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).indexOnly(user).buildMixedIndex(BACKING_INDEX)\n" +
"mgmt.commit()"
```